# Copy a file from the app bundle to the user's Application Support folder

Tags: xcode, cocoa, macos, nsfilemanager

I'm making an app where I need to copy certain file from the app bundle to the user's Application Support folder. This is the code I'm using actually:

```
NSBundle *thisBundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
NSString *executableName = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"CFBundleExecutable"];
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSApplicationSupportDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *userpath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
userpath = [userpath stringByAppendingPathComponent:executableName];    // The file will go in this directory
NSString *saveFilePath = [userpath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"db.sqlite"];
NSFileManager *fileManager = [[NSFileManager alloc] init];
[fileManager copyItemAtPath:[thisBundle pathForResource:@"db" ofType:@"sqlite"] toPath:saveFilePath error:NULL];
```

But this doesn't copies anything, BTW this is a Mac app.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally got it working with adding

```
if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:userpath] == NO)
    [fileManager createDirectoryAtPath:userpath withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:nil];
```

And the resulting code is:

```
NSBundle *thisBundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];

NSString *executableName = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"CFBundleExecutable"];
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSApplicationSupportDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *userpath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
userpath = [userpath stringByAppendingPathComponent:executableName];    // The file will go in this directory
NSString *saveFilePath = [userpath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"db.sqlite"];
NSFileManager *fileManager = [[NSFileManager alloc] init];
if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:userpath] == NO)
    [fileManager createDirectoryAtPath:userpath withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:nil];

[fileManager copyItemAtPath:[thisBundle pathForResource:@"db" ofType:@"sqlite"] toPath:saveFilePath error:NULL];
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to double-check your file paths:

```
NSLog(@"src: %@", [thisBundle pathForResource:@"db" ofType:@"sqlite"]);
NSLog(@"dst: %@", saveFilePath);
```

Comment: Alright got it working with:     if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:userpath] == NO)
        [fileManager createDirectoryAtPath:userpath withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:nil];

Comment: I have got the code working.. however there is a problem. Say the file size is 3.6 mb.. then only the file copied to the documents directory is 200kb only.. it is partially copied. Are there any limitations for it??